# How to go back to multiple screen in TabNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my `App.js` I have `StackNavigator` (see
[online code snippet 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ge9xyo?file=App.js)) and then my `TabNavigator.js` (see [online code snippet 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ge9xyo?file=AppTabNavigator.js)).

I have:

```
Tab1: DetailUser -> DetailDiary -> Edit1 -> Edit2
Tab2: Search -> DetailUser -> DetailDiary -> Edit1 -> Edit2
```

After finishing `Edit2` I will go back to `DetailDiary` with new content so I save it `this.props.navigation.state.key ( ex value key is keyDetailUser)` in `DetailDiary` and after `Edit2` is finished I call this function:
[image: screenshot]

But with both cases nothing happens.

If use `this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailDiary")` in android when click back in device it can't go back to `DetailUser`.

How can I go back from `Edit2` to `DetailDiary` in second tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're only changing the params in the route so you haven't called for the navigator to change screens. You'll want to pass `keyDetailUser` as props when you navigate to `DetailDiary` screen. Try this code sample. Hope it helps.

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'DetailDiary', // navigates to this route
    params: {key: keyDetailUser}, // passes these params as props
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

Comment: how I can get key params from DetailDiary? When console.log nextProps and nextState in function shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) both return undefined

Comment: Try `this.props.navigation.state.params.key`

Comment: it return undefined

Comment: Are you calling `this.props.navigation.state.params.key` inside the render function?

Comment: sorry, when I call it in shouldcomponentUpdate() funcation, in render() it have value. tks you